# HSRP does not work on two switches. Cisco

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree, hsrp, vrrp

The problem is this: clients receive IP addresses from the L31 DHCP server, but they cannot ping the gateway, although HSRP seems to be working, there are no problems, I suspect that this is a bug in EVE, but maybe you will find something....

[image: Network Topology]

L31

```
    Current configuration : 3892 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 17:20:55 UTC Sat Mar 18 2023
!
version 15.1
service tcp-keepalives-in
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname L31
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 4 erMlKVR4hcu3p9q96fOSMn1EQW35g3Tp7Z9Woacdb4I
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 122A0E1E1E075F5D6B
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login deafult local
aaa authorization exec default local if-authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
!
ip cef
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.60 192.168.10.64
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.92 192.168.10.94
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.108 192.168.10.112
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.116 192.168.10.120
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN10_DHCP
 network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.192
 dns-server 192.168.10.62
 default-router 192.168.10.62
 domain-name raw.trans.kst
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN20_DHCP
 network 192.168.10.64 255.255.255.224
 default-router 192.168.10.94
 dns-server 192.168.10.94
 domain-name raw.trans.kst
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN30_DHCP
 network 192.168.10.96 255.255.255.240
 default-router 192.168.10.110
 domain-name raw.trans.kst
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN50_DHCP
 network 192.168.10.112 255.255.255.248
 default-router 192.168.10.118
 domain-name raw.trans.kst
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
ip domain-name raw.trans.kst
login delay 1
login on-failure log
login on-success log
no ipv6 cef
ipv6 multicast rpf use-bgp
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30,55,666 priority 24576
!
!
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
ip ssh time-out 1
ip ssh authentication-retries 2
ip ssh logging events
ip ssh version 2
!
track 1 interface Ethernet0/0 line-protocol
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 channel-group 1 mode active
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 duplex auto
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.168.10.61 255.255.255.192
 standby 1 ip 192.168.10.62
 standby 1 priority 110
 standby 1 preempt
 standby 1 track 1 decrement 11
!
interface Vlan20
 ip address 192.168.10.93 255.255.255.224
 standby 2 ip 192.168.10.94
 standby 2 priority 110
 standby 2 preempt
 standby 2 track 1 decrement 10
!
interface Vlan30
 ip address 192.168.10.109 255.255.255.240
 standby 3 ip 192.168.10.110
 standby 3 priority 110
 standby 3 preempt
 standby 3 track 1 decrement 10
!
interface Vlan55
 ip address 192.168.10.117 255.255.255.248
 standby 55 ip 192.168.10.118
 standby 55 priority 110
 standby 55 preempt
 standby 55 track 1 decrement 10
!
interface Vlan666
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
no ip http server
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 session-timeout 35791
 exec-timeout 35791 0
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 session-timeout 35791
 exec-timeout 35791 0
 session-limit 5
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
!
end
```

L32

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 3054 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 16:44:53 UTC Sat Mar 18 2023 by admin
!
version 15.1
service tcp-keepalives-in
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname L32
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 4 erMlKVR4hcu3p9q96fOSMn1EQW35g3Tp7Z9Woacdb4I
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 0468000F032D1F1748
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authorization exec default local if-authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
!
ip cef
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
ip domain-name raw.trans.kst
login on-failure log
login on-success log
no ipv6 cef
ipv6 multicast rpf use-bgp
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
spanning-tree vlan 10,20,30,55,666 priority 28672
!
!
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
ip ssh time-out 1
ip ssh authentication-retries 2
ip ssh logging events
ip ssh version 2
!
track 1 interface Ethernet0/0 line-protocol
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
 switchport
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 channel-group 1 mode passive
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 channel-group 1 mode passive
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 duplex auto
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.168.10.60 255.255.255.192
 standby 1 ip 192.168.10.62
 standby 1 priority 101
 standby 1 preempt
 standby 1 track 1 decrement 10
!
interface Vlan20
 ip address 192.168.10.92 255.255.255.224
 standby 2 ip 192.168.10.94
 standby 2 priority 101
 standby 2 preempt
 standby 2 track 1 decrement 10
!
interface Vlan30
 ip address 192.168.10.108 255.255.255.240
 standby 3 ip 192.168.10.110
 standby 3 priority 105
 standby 3 preempt
 standby 3 track 1 decrement 10
!
interface Vlan55
 ip address 192.168.10.116 255.255.255.248
 standby 55 ip 192.168.10.118
 standby 55 priority 105
 standby 55 preempt
 standby 55 track 1 decrement 10
!
!
no ip http server
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 session-timeout 35791
 exec-timeout 35791 0
 session-limit 55
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
!
end
```

L22

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2297 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 16:27:19 UTC Sat Mar 18 2023 by admin
!
version 15.1
service tcp-keepalives-in
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname L22
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 4 erMlKVR4hcu3p9q96fOSMn1EQW35g3Tp7Z9Woacdb4I
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 01200D0D5707555660
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authorization exec default local if-authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
!
ip cef
!
!
ip domain-name raw.trans.kst
login delay 1
login on-failure log
login on-success log
no ipv6 cef
ipv6 multicast rpf use-bgp
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
!
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
lldp run
!
ip ssh time-out 3
ip ssh authentication-retries 2
ip ssh logging events
ip ssh version 2
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 666
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,55,666
 switchport mode trunk
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky
 duplex auto
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky
 duplex auto
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 shutdown
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 shutdown
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 shutdown
 duplex auto
!
interface Vlan55
 ip address 192.168.10.113 255.255.255.248
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.10.118
!
no ip http server
!
!
access-list 199 permit ip any any log
!
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 session-timeout 35791
 access-class 199 in
 exec-timeout 35791 0
 session-limit 5
 logging synchronous
 transport input ssh
!
end
```

[image]